# C# - Casting a Generic Delegate to a Non Generic Delegate

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, casting, delegates

I have a generic delegate that accepts a argument, `Args<T>`. I also have a normal delegate which accepts `Args`.

```cs
delegate Task ExampleDelegate<T>(Args<T> args)

delegate Task ExampleDelegate(Args args)
```

`Args<T>` extends from `Args`

```cs
public class Args {

}

public class Args<T> : Args {

}
```

I am currently extending my non generic interfaces/classes which use `ExampleDelegate` to create new generic interfaces/classes using `ExampleDelegate<T>`.

Since all of them extend the non-generic versions, it has been painless to extend them so far until I had to override a method which accepts `ExampleDelegate`.

I haven't been able to cast `ExampleDelegate<T>` into `ExampleDelegate` since the signatures don't match.

One of the ways I was able to this was,

```cs
ExampleDelegate<SomeClass> genericDelegate= //some method

//First case
ExampleDelegate nonGenericDelegate = args => genericDelegate(args as Args<SomeClass>);

//Second case
genericDelegate = argsT => nonGenericDelegate(argsT);
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Update:
Is it possible to do this without creating an anonymous method like the one above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there any better way of doing this?*

Probably yes, but we don't know what you are trying to do so we can't help you

*I don't see why I need to cast explicitly in the second case as well?*

You don't...?
Here is some code that compiles just fine:

```
class TestClass
{
    void DoStuff()
    {
        ExampleDelegate nonGeneric = a => { };
        ExampleDelegate<int> generic = b => nonGeneric(b);
    }
}

delegate void ExampleDelegate(Args args);

delegate void ExampleDelegate<T>(Args<T> args);

class Args<T> : Args {}

class Args {}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing out the second case works without casting. I must have overlooked something, I have to check my project again. My main question is if I can cast it without using an anonymous method?

Comment: If you can cast what?

Comment: The delegates. Is it possible to cast the generic delegate to nongeneric without using any anonymous methods?

Comment: You can't cast delegates into other delegates in the first place. I see you updated your question. The answer is no, you can't

Comment: So anonymous methods are my only option. Thank you for your answer, I'll see if I can implement something different.

Comment: I guess I misspoke. Anonymous methods are not your only option. You can do this: `ExampleDelegate<int> generic = new ExampleDelegate<int>(nonGeneric);`

Comment: Oh, thank you. I will give that a try as well.